# Objective C: Send coredata objects by imessage & eMail

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have coredata objects of Entity A (with a link to Entity B). And I want to enable the user to send objects of Entity A by Mail or iMessage to other people. If they are linked to Entity B, this should be set to nil when sent. B is like describing which category object of entity A is. And this is specific for any user anyway so I want to nil it. But how can I send it? And later on on the other user device if clicked on it show a dialogue "Open in ..."?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for this - you need to design and implement your own scheme. This also involves formatting and export of the data you need to transfer and importing it at the other end. If you can format and fit this data into URL query parameters then it'll be very easy. If you can't then you need to export a file and register to open that file type instead of using a custom URL scheme.